# Was the Chasam Sofer known for having an interesting way of learning?

Tags: history, torah-study, mistakes, emes-truth-honesty, chatam-sofer

I have a lot of experience learning Gemara and find myself oft dealing with the views of the Achronim to understand the Pshat in Rishonim. Unfortunately, I have inside me a slight aversion to the great Chasam Sofer's style of learning and do not find that he goes according to the normal Pshat. This bothers me because he was a great Zaddik. To counter this feeling I am trying to find out if my feeling has any basis and if yes, where does it come from. So...

1. Does anyone concur with my feeling about the Chasam Sofer's learning?
2. If yes, can you link to a source where I can read more about it and what other Gedolim held of his style?
3. Although not strictly related to the question, was the Chasam Sofer accepted by all or were there any Gedolim who were against him?

I do not mean to belittle the holy Chasam Sofer, I am just interested in finding out more about him. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Truth Seeker, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! The Chasam Sofer is definitely known to be a very original and creative thinker. There are many different styles of commentary, and some many not be a good "fit" for one's specific intellectual personality.

Comment: @Dave thanks, but I find the Chasam Sofer different from 95 percent of the other Meforshim!

Comment: I could give you a whole list of meforshim that are different from 95% (or more!) of the others: The Rogetchover, R' Yaakov Emden, Birkas Shmuel, Kehillos Yaakov, etc. etc. (each in its own way).

Comment: @Dave None of those Meforshim are indeed learnt as Pshat Seforim [save perhaps the Bircas Shmuel]. The Chasam Sofer though is almost universally quoted.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the Chasam Sofer's *derech halimud*, so I can't really comment on questions 1 and 2. However, with regard to question 3, to my knowledge the Chasam Sofer was universally recognized as one of the greatest halachic authorities of his time. I would point out that it is not unusual for poskim to have a rather different style of learning than the one most of us are familiar with from yeshiva. (See, for example, the *Dibros Moshe* of R' Moshe Feinstein.)

Comment: I understand if it is not feasible, but it would be helpful if you could give some more details on exactly how you find the Chasam Sofer's approach to be so different from everyone else.

Comment: @LazerA prob not so feasible, but then again I am asking whether other people have already experienced this, not to go and check now ;) . I happen to find the Dibros Moshe quite on target actually, but each to his own. Which you may tell me about the Chasam Sofer!!!

Comment: I agree with you, his approach is different. But I don't have an aversion to it, I actually have a deep appreciation for it. But I do have a question how it was as accepted as it was.

Comment: See the introduction to Dor Revii.